# ATI Temperature Monitoring

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, amd-radeon, temperature

I'm trying to monitor the temperature of my GPUs (multiple ATI 5970) in my computation cluster. Problem is that the aticonfig tool does not work in headless mode

```
# /usr/bin/aticonfig --od-gettemperature
No protocol specified
ERROR - X needs to be running to perform ATI Overdrive(TM) commands
```

and even worse if I try to run aticonfig with my monitoring user (munin) it will ask to be executed as root. Is there a simple way to read the temperature of the GPUs without having to resort to X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
aticonfig --odgt --adapter=0
aticonfig --odgt --adapter=1
...
```

Root permissions may be necessary, try it out.

Comment: Explain what the command and arguments do?

Comment: `aticonfig --help` lists the available options.  For `--odgt` aka `--od-gettemperature` it states _Returns the temperature reported by any thermal sensors available on the adapter_.  I didn't need `export DISPLAY=:0` nor superuser privileges YMMV.   +1 thanks =)

Comment: As a little extra: to get the temperature of all adapters at once just use `DISPLAY=:0 aticonfig --adapter=all --odgt`. That will get all the adapters attached to X instance 0.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem trying to run aticonfig as user www-data for Cacti.

By doing a visudo and adding the following to the sudoers file. (You will want to change beast to your hostname and www-data to munin in your case.)

```
www-data        beast = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/aticonfig
```

With this I've been able to run

```
sudo /usr/bin/aticonfig
```

as user www-data however I'm still running into some issue with Cacti.

Hope this helps.